# How can I access a 32 or 64 bit integral value similar to GCC's sync_fetch_and_add in a CONST method?

Tags: c++, caching, atomic

I am used to using pthread mutexts, etc (or boost equivalents) to synchronize/protect access to shared across threads data.

More recently, I've had to work with code where atomics are used in places to avoid some of the overhead of mutex locking etc. I am, for the purposes of this question, asking more about HOW to do this instead of whether it is WORTH doing ;)

Code is compiled with GCC 4.4.7, iir and on Linux x86-64.
I often ran across calls of the sort: `InterlockedCopy(variable)`

which is typedef'ed to

```
__sync_fetch_and_add(&(__var__), 0)
```

Now, this seems to fit the bill nicely, except that I have this habit of wanting to make methods that do not MODIFY a member be ... const.

So, if I have a "status" flag variable that I use, currently a uint32_t (but I am willing to change types or use typedef sig_int_t etc) and I wish to set it to some enum value in one thread and read it in another via a const accessor, how can I do so without making the accessor non-const or making the accessed member "mutable"?

Pardon my ignorance, but I was thinking: GCC has a lot of atomic primitives. Including ones to pre or post add, subtract, and, or, etc values and return them atomically (with included full memory barrier) - why is there no:

```
__sync_fetch(__var__) built-in.
```

Is it because it is not needed. That we can simply use a normal uint32_t and:

```
T1(CPU0): __sync_synchronize(); statusFlag = ENUM_VALUE;

T2(CPU1): if (statusFlag == ENUM_VALUE)
          { // do stuff ... }
          __sync_synchronize();
```

Or some such - that:
1. Ensures atomic access on properly aligned integral variables.
2. Ensures that when the flag is updated in one thread that a method that checks this flag (not in a loop) in another thread will either see it the next time it checks that flag in the other thread (allowing for time for the coherency 'stuff' I am trying to learn about - to happen...)

(so hard to TYPE this question non-interactively ;) - sorry)

Mainly, I cannot imagine GCC left out a plain non-mutating "fetch" **unless** it was because it obviously is not needed since it is achievable trivially via other existing means.

Answer (score 2):

The line `__sync_fetch_and_add(&(__var__), 0)` actually does something slightly different than just fetch the variable.  It takes ownership of the cache line.  I'm not sure if that's intended but that is what it does.  So, changing it will change the semantics of the program.

The x86-64 architecture is strongly ordered though, so you generally don't need to worry about memory re-orderings other than the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you post me in the direction of something with more data about these than the gcc-atomics part of the gcc document? there you only get a single line description for some of the primitives.

Comment: @Varsuuk The GCC atomics should essentially map one-to-one to instructions like CAS and the lock prefix, so the best reference is honestly the intel architecture [manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).  Paul McKenney's [paper](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2009.04.05a.pdf) might also help.